# Register user name with apostrophe (') Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an app in Android where users have to register, and they have to intruduce a name. The problem is that when a user introduce the `apostrophe (')` in his name (eg Satck'developers). Then in the app I have problems with the database SQLite.

> UPDATE user SET name='othername' WHERE name='Stack'developers'`)

This causes a SQLiteException.

How  can I manage this situation in Android? How can I not to allow user to put `apostrophe (')`?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you really use a raw sql query for the update? Do not do that, since it is vulnerable to SQL injections. There you go -> https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html#UpdateDbRow

Comment: Hi Christopher! I do not use a raw sql query for any sentence. I wrote the syntax error! The update sentece I do it like this: `db.update(TABLE_USER, values, "name='" + user_name+ "'", null);` Thank you for your advice!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you dont want to allow ' then you need to validate you input before storing in db. Something like

```
if(editText.getText().toString.contains("'")){
// show invalid error message
} else{
// store to db
}
```

Comment: Nice idea! Good Vardaan! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape reserved characters to avoid SQL injections. There are built-in methods which do that automatically.

```
int update(SQLiteDatabase db, String originalName, String newName) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("name", newName);
    return db.update("user", values, "name = ?", new String[]{originalName});
}
```

Comment: Hi BladeCoder! Very interesting. Your are right! But I dont see very clear how works this method or exists ohter built-in methods that find escape reserved charecters and not only apostrophe ('). How can I implement in my editText where get the name before register in the BBDD? Thank you.

Comment: Basically all methods on `SQLiteDatabase` taking a `String[]` argument will properly escape these values and use them as replacements for all the "?" in the query body. Also ContentValues are escaped. Escaping will be performed by native SQLite code. You simply need to pass the value from `EditText.getText().toString()` inside the `String[]` array, or inside ContentValues, depending on which method you use.